# jQuery Ajax not catching the data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Add-more-posts.php:

```
ob_start();
//SOME HTML CONTENTS!
$contents = ob_get_clean();

if(!empty($contents)){
    echo $contents;
}else{
    echo 'end';
}
```

jQuery in Index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#get-more').click(function(){
        $('#get-more').hide();      
        $('#loading-img').slideDown();
        var post_id = $('div.more').attr('id');
        if(!$("#empty-div").hasClass('ended')){
        $.post("add_more_posts.php", {'post_id': post_id} , function(data){
            if(data == 'end'){
                $("#empty-div").addClass('ended');
                $('.more').remove();
                $('#get-more').hide();
                $('#loading-img').fadeOut();
                $('div#AddPosts').append('Finished Loading!');
            }else{
                if(!$("#empty-div").hasClass('ended')){
                    $('.more').remove();
                    $('#loading-img').remove();
                    $('div#AddPosts').append(data);
                    $('#get-more').show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it is not ending. It is not catching the data == 'end' but rather it is appending 'end' into my div in my index.php.

What is the problem?

Comment: have you confirmed what you are getting in `data` in the ajax success callback

Comment: @dakait What do you mean? The Else{...} part works...but if(data == 'end') does not work!

Comment: that is what im saying when you want `if(data=='end')` to execute what is the content of `data` im sure its not `end` because from the server you are returning `$contents`... what does `$contents` contain may be you wanted to do `if(data != 'end')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("add_more_posts.php", {post_id: post_id} , function(data){
```